# Regex with jinja?

Tags: regex, jinja2

I would like to use regexes in Jinja as:

```
{{ foo | regex_replace('[^a-z0-9]', '_') }}
```

I've read that [ansible](/questions/tagged/ansible) provides [additional filters](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#other-useful-filters) such as `regex_replace`.

Would it be the best solution to define a custom filter in this particular case?

Comment: I cannot see what your goal is except for replacing everything that is not a letter or number with an underscore. Depending on why you do that and how often and what else you need a custom filter might be necessary. But what is not working for you so you dont roll with this?

Comment: I would like to use jinja as a standalone template engine to convert source-template files into C/C++ files by using data located in a database. Defining a custom filter will not be possible inside the template so I will be forced to hard code the filter inside my template engine.

Comment: Yes, you can create a custom filter.